# FluentNHibernate Tutorial issue

Tags: c#, .net, hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have been trying to complete the [FluentNHibernate Tutorial](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started) and have been having some trouble to get it to compile. I believe I've done everything in the tutorial as it says, and have compared my code to the source on GitHub, but I keep getting this exception in this code:

```
        private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
    {
        if (File.Exists(DbFile))
            File.Delete(DbFile);
        new SchemaExport(config)
        .Create(false,true);
    }
```

Which is called from:

```
        private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
            SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
            .UsingFile("FluentNHTry.db")
            )
            .Mappings( m=> m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
                .BuildSessionFactory();

        }
```

The exception is:

```
NHibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: System.Char
   at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.CollectionBinder.BindCollectionSecondPass(ICollectionPropertiesMapping collectionMapping, Collection model, IDictionary`2 persistentClasses, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.CollectionBinder.<>c__DisplayClass13.<AddCollectionSecondPass>b__12(IDictionary`2 persistentClasses)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.SecondPassCompile()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.GenerateDropSchemaScript(Dialect dialect)
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Initialize()
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute(Action`1 scriptAction, Boolean export, Boolean justDrop)
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute(Boolean script, Boolean export, Boolean justDrop)
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Create(Boolean script, Boolean export)
   at FluentNHTry.Program.BuildSchema(Configuration config) in c:\Users\JMcKenn1\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\FluentNHTry\FluentNHTry\Program.cs:line 105
   at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration()}
```

And I have no idea how to fix it. If someone could please point me towards where I'm going wrong, that would be great.

Note - I've not created a database, as I believe the code creates one for me, but it doesn't look to me like this error relates to there not being a database.

Edit - As I was asked, here are the mapping and entity classes:

Mappings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using FluentNHTry.Entities;

namespace FluentNHTry.Mappings
{
    public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.FirstName);
            Map(x => x.LastName);
            References(x => x.Store);
        }
    }

    public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
    {
        public ProductMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Name);
            Map(x => x.Price);
            HasManyToMany(x => x.StoresStockedIn)
                .Cascade.All()
                .Inverse()
                .Table("StoreProduct");
        }
    }

    public class StoreMap : ClassMap<Store>
    {
        public StoreMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Name);
            HasMany(x => x.Name)
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.All();
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Products)
                .Cascade.All()
                .Table("StoreProduct");
        }
    }
}
```

Entities:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FluentNHTry.Entities
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public  virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

    }

    public class Product
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual double Price { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Store> StoresStockedIn { get; protected set; }

        public Product()
        {
            StoresStockedIn = new List<Store>();
        }
    }
    public class Store
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Employee> Staff { get; set; }

        public Store()
        {
            Products = new List<Product>();
            Staff = new List<Employee>();
        }

        public virtual void AddProduct(Product product)
        {
            product.StoresStockedIn.Add(this);
            Products.Add(product);
        }

        public virtual void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            employee.Store = this;
            Staff.Add(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your mapping and entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a typo:

```
public class StoreMap : ClassMap<Store>
{
    public StoreMap()
    {
        // ... other properties ...
        HasMany(x => x.Name) // <-- this line is the problem
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
        // ... other properties ...
    }
}
```

That should be:

```
        HasMany(x => x.Staff)
```

You can tell that this is the problem by the error message:

> Association references unmapped class: System.Char

This says that somewhere you told NHibernate that an entity has a collection of child entities of type `char`.  `char` is not an entity, hence the problem.  `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so we're probably looking for a `HasMany` being applied to a string property.

`HasMany(x => x.Name)` is the culprit.